# Extracting Data from JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a large JSON item returned through a REST API, I wont junk up this with the full text but here is the code I am currently using:

```
import urllib2
import json
req =     urllib2.Request
('http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/
pollster/api/polls.json?state=IA')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
decode = json.loads(the_page)
#print = decode #removed, because it is not actually related to the question
print decode
```

I have been trying to extract information out of it such as the date polls are updated, the actual data from the polls etc (particularly the presidential polls) but I am having trouble returning any data at all. Can anyone assist?

EDIT:
The actual question is how to query data from the returned array/dict

Comment: you should read a bit on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html Data sctructures, and get back to us with a concrete example of what you have attempted with any error message

Comment: `print = decode` What exactly are you trying to achieve??

Comment: Code works fine for me if you change `print = decode` to `print decode`. For more readable output to find which keys are for date polls and data, use `pprint.pprint(decode)`

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Thank you! The print = decode was a typo actually, i normally do print decode but i added it back in to be complete with my code despite it not being relevant to what i am asking. Unfortunately i dont think i have been very clear with my question. I get returns such as :[{u'last_updated': u'2016-06-16T15:48:18.784+00:00', u'end_date': u'2016-06-13', u'pollster': u'PPP (D-Constitutional Responsibility Project)', u'affiliation': u'Dem', u'partisan': u'Sponsor', u'survey_houses': and i want to extract information from this, how would i do that? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you overwrite `print` with your data, instead of printing the data. Just remove the `=` in the last line and it should work fine:

```
print decode
```

If you want to use Python 3, you need parenthesis for `print`. This would look like this:

```
print(decode)
```

Edit: As you updated your question, here an answer to your actual question: The data is returned as a combination of dicts and lists by the `loads` function. Hence you can also access the data like a dict/list. For example, to get the `last_updated` field of all polls in one list, you can do something like this:

```
all_last_updated = [poll['last_updated'] for poll in decode]
```

Or to just get the end date of all polls sponsored by "Constitutional Responsibility Project", you could do this:

```
end_dates = [poll['end_date'] for poll in decode if any(sponsor['name'] == 'Constitutional Responsibility Project' for sponsor in poll['sponsors'])]
```

Or if you just want the id of the first poll in the list, do:

```
the_id = decode[0]['id']
```

You access anything you want from the json in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you! The print = decode was a typo actually, i normally do print decode but i added it back in to be complete with my code despite it not being relevant to what i am asking. Unfortunately i dont think i have been very clear with my question. I get returns such as :[{u'last_updated': u'2016-06-16T15:48:18.784+00:00', u'end_date': u'2016-06-13', u'pollster': u'PPP (D-Constitutional Responsibility Project)', u'affiliation': u'Dem', u'partisan': u'Sponsor', u'survey_houses': and i want to extract information from this, how would i do that? –

Comment: I just updated my answer to match the updated question. Does this help you figure out how to get the data you want?

Comment: Thank you! This was very very helpful! cal I return lists in this fashion? for example, there is a section of polls for {"name":"Registered Voters","observations":630,"margin_of_error":3.9,"responses":  and the value for "responses" is the actual poll date. How would I retrieve that?

Comment: Well first you need to get the `poll`/s (maybe filtered as shown above), then you get the list of `questions` and again select the one/filter the ones wanted. Again the same for the `subpopulations`. After that you can just get the `responses` list from you subpopulation.

Comment: would it be some variation of what you provided with end_dates = [poll['end_date'] for poll in decode if any(sponsor['name'] == 'Constitutional Responsibility Project' for sponsor in poll['sponsors'])] except change it to select for candidate names (ie Clinton). How would I then query the "value" field of that list? I want to get values associated with the candidate. I'm sorry i'm just a little confused on how to do this and I really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Once you got your `response` object, just do `response['value']` to get the value. If you do something complex to access an object, you can also just store it in an variable and then proceed with the object. This can make it easier to work out how to get to the data you want. Just take it step by step: Start by "How do I get the poll/s I want?". And the work forward from the `poll`to the `question` ("How do I get that question from the poll?") and so on.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you do

```
print = decode
```

instead, if you are using python 2 do

```
print decode
```

or in python 3 do

```
print(decode)
```

Comment: Thank you! The print = decode was a typo actually, i normally do print decode but i added it back in to be complete with my code despite it not being relevant to what i am asking. Unfortunately i dont think i have been very clear with my question. I get returns such as :[{u'last_updated': u'2016-06-16T15:48:18.784+00:00', u'end_date': u'2016-06-13', u'pollster': u'PPP (D-Constitutional Responsibility Project)', u'affiliation': u'Dem', u'partisan': u'Sponsor', u'survey_houses':    and i want to extract information from this, how would i do that?